# Blueimp fileupload send json object to controller on submit

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, json

This is my first question here so please be gentle... I have a cshtml (ASP.NET MVC 5) page where I want to upload documents to certain rows (in a dataTable on the page) which I already store into a json. The json looks like this:

**JSON:**

```
var jsonDataIds = [
{"Id":"9f835451-14ba-e511-a63e-643150188f7f",.. more data},
{"Id":"a0835451-14ba-e511-a63e-643150188f7f",.. more data},
{"Id":"a1835451-14ba-e511-a63e-643150188f7f",.. more data}];
```

I am using blueimp fileupload to handle the file upload.

Here's the script initializing the element in my page:

**Javascript:**

```
$("#inFile").fileupload({
            url: 'attachFile',
            dataType: 'json',
            formData: {ecId:jsonDataIds,usrId:"@User.GetId()"},
            add: function(e, data) {
                fileData = data;
            },
            done: function(event, data) {
                alert(data.message);
            },
            fail: function(event, data) {
                alert("Error uploading the file.");
            }
        });

        $("#btnUpload").on('click', function() {
            if(fileData){
                fileData.submit();
            }
        });
```

When I check in the controller `attachFile`, the `usrId` is received, the file is received, but the Ids isn't.

I think there might be a limitation that you can only send strings and not a json object.

**Controller**: (partial)

```
    public ActionResult attachFile(List<MyModel> ecId, string modUsrId) 
// modUsrId is ok, ecId is NULL
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++) 
// Request.Files.Count is ok
```

Comment: The closing square parenthesis is missing in the definition of jsonDataIds. Of course, I know that it is only a typo in your message here in SO

Comment: Thanks Marco! I will edit :)

Comment: I kinda made it work now... I made the json into a string and sent it to the controller and then deserialized the string into a List of my model. I don't like the solution tho... I'll wait and see if there's any more.

Comment: Have you tried with a different name for the Id column ? Could it be a bug in the library ?

Comment: Yes, that's not actually the real name. I tried xvID and eccsId.
I do think it might be a bug in the library. It seems it's using json to send the data or something like that. I would have to look in deeper.

Comment: I would suggest to user Chrome Dev Tools or Fiddler to verify what data is sent. Then you can understand is it a problem with javascript library or with server deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

"Issue" was fixed by sending the json object as a string and then serializing on the controller end.